# STM32 hardware design for clock

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, oscillator, clock

I want to develop my own PCB using STM32F4. I want to use an external 16MHz clock. Where do I have to connect the clock, OSCIN32-OSCOUT32 (pins 3 and 4) or OSCIN-OSCOUT (HSE) (pins 5 and 6 in STM32F446RET?)

I can see in the development board's schematic where there is an empty footprint for X3 (pins 5 and 6) and I don't know if it is using the debugger's clock.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes all packages of the same processor may not have all pins connected to it. Did you not check the manual?  community.st.com may be the best place to ask questions about ST processors.  Check this link:  https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009Xkhf8SAB/stm32f4-external-oscillator

Comment: Yes, i did. It is connected, but I don't know if I can use just one or I need both or if I am using just one which one.

Comment: Why don't you read the datasheet or hardware design appnote? Do you want to use an external clock, or a crystal? Why 16 MHz? If you use the PLL, it will need to be divided down to 1 or 2 MHz anyway.

Comment: Please note that microcontrollers typically come with 3 clocking options: _internal clock_ (the whole oscillator is inside the MCU), _external quartz_ (an amplifier inside the MCU drives an external crystal - probably the most common) or _external clock_ (the whole oscillator is external and the MCU has a clock input pin). I'm guessing that you are actually looking for the external quartz option?

Comment: @Lundin Im using an external crystal oscillator (ABLS7M2-16MHz-D2Y) connected directly to OSCIN-OSCOUT pins. I set the frequency and input in CubeIDE. Together with the oscillator I have got two capacitors (value = 2*(Cload-Cstray) = 26 pF).

Comment: @DevelopingElectronics That's a _crystal_, it got _2_ pins, it is _not_ an oscillator.

Comment: @Lundin oh, sorry, so, is it my connection ok?

Comment: What connection? Please post the schematic. For the typical Pierce Oscillator circuit used by most MCUs, you'd also have 1Mohm in parallel with the crystal. Though I'm not really the right person to explain the theory behind it all.

Comment: I am using a jumper to choose a crystal. Just one is connected. I have seen this schematic in other circuits. I haven't seen the 1Mohm resistor in any, but I don't know, maybe it's that. The thing is I am having some trouble running code in my PCB to blink a led (the problem is solved by lowering the frequency in CubeIDE clock configuration).

Comment: The info you seek is in datasheets and appnotes. Switching between two oscilllators can be problematic, why does not a single oscillator suffice? The caps likely need to be different for both oscillators. 26pF also exceeds recommended capacitor range. And the higher the frequency is, the less margin there is for proper startup and operation.

Comment: @Justme I don't switch between them when the PCB is programmed. This is just an idea to add flexibility in this testing board (kind of a development board, to try which one would be better in the final one). The official development kit includes a 20pF capacitor with the crystal. I use 26 pF (value = 2*(Cload-Cstray), which is the same value for both capacitors as they have both the same Cload.

Comment: If the crystal requires capacitors that are out of range for the MCU, do you think you should maybe look for a more suitable crystal? Like why the frequencies are required to be so high, as the 26 MHz is also the maximum.

Comment: Just a word of advice: you should not need two crystals/oscillators. The PLL in the STM32 is pretty flexible, so really any external clock source that's a multiple of 1 or 2 MHz should work by changing the PLL settings. There is also the concern of routing your clock signal through a pin header/jumper; depending on the clock source type that may destabilize things or radiate a lot of EMI.

Comment: I do understand that the evaluation board has *two* options, but why wouldn't you consider the data sheet for 1 crystal?

Comment: Where can I check that the capacitors are "out of range" for the MCU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where do I have to connect the clock,
> Be careful when using the word *clock*. Here it means the output of a self contained *external* oscillator. The schematic shows that the oscillator is inside to the micro, but using and external crystal. The crystal does not supply clocking signals.

There is a lot of information in the data sheets and manuals provided by ST. Usually there are three. All this information will be found there.

1. The user manual
2. The datasheet
3. The programmers manual

Research/train on oscillators, specifically crystal oscillators and on how crystals work.

If an external self contained oscillator like a TCXO for example is used, then you would connect the oscillator output to the PH0-OSC_IN pin. Then the PH1-OSC_OUT pin can be used for something else. The output of this oscillator can be called a clock and would then be the HSE clocking source within the chip.

If a crystal is used with the HSE oscillator inside the chip, it is connected to both PH0-OSC_IN and PH1-OSC_OUT pins. A Pierce oscillator is formed across an internal inverter. A feedback resistor between the two pins is provided internally to provide bias into the linear region of the inverter, so the 1 M \$ \Omega \$ resistor mentioned in the comments is already provided. The signal on PH1-OSC_OUT is closer to sinusoidal than square. Internal conditioning turns it into a *clock*.

The schematic shows the intention to choose one of two crystals using jumper pins.

1. The load capacitors C5 and C6 can be (are) different for different crystal frequencies.
2. The jumpers can leave a small residual capacitance that prevents complete isolation of the crystal so the unused crystal may interfere with the performance or start-up of the oscillator.

I recommend that you use a **such as** this [Raltron Electronics](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/raltron-electronics/RTXE-104ED333-C-26-000-TR/14558650) TCXO. I am not suggesting this particular one but it is an example. These are low cost and take up very little space on the PCB. There is often an enable/disable pin that places the output into high-Z state to allow selection.
See below for an example. The switches can be trace jumpers (preferably). The two capacitors are decoupling, one for each chip.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXpaNE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Which would be the formula to calculate cap values? I have read that my values are too high but I just followed C = 2 * (Cload-Cstray). In this case, the Cload was the same for the two crystals, that is why the same capacitors are used for both of them.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, there is some confusion over terminology.

For high-speed external (HSE) clock reference, you should use the OSC_IN/OSC_OUT pins. How you connect them depends on the type of clock reference you choose:

Per the reference manual, section 6.2.1:
[image]

If you use a crystal (as shown in your schematic), you would connect it to OSC_IN/OSC_OUT with the appropriate load caps (per the crystal's datasheet).

If you use a logic-level clock source, like a self contained silicon oscillator, you would leave the OSC_OUT unconnected.

I also would recommend against putting both crystal circuits on your board, as you have shown in your schematic. The clock signals should be routed close to the MCU, and not have any stray excursions (like through a jumper) to minimize loading effects that could change the resonant frequency. Additionally, the PLL in the F446 is really flexible, and any external clock source in a multiple of 1MHz or 2MHz will work. If you are proposing mulitple footprints for BOM flexibility, that is fine, but I'd recommend just finding alternate parts that share the footprint, rather than planning and routing two separate clock sources or crystals.

Answer (score -1):

According to STM32F446RE datasheet, OSC_IN/OSC_OUT pins are used for HSE (high speed external) oscillators. You can use oscillators in range of 1-50 MHz. And OSC32 pins are used for LSE (low speed external) oscillators. It can be between 32.768/1000 kHz. There are two tables in datasheet external clock sources part 6.3.9, page 101.

Comment: You are mixing oscillators and crystals.  The question was about crystals, not oscillators. You are on wrong datasheet page for that.